# Uploading a Dataframe to AWS S3 Bucket from SageMaker

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I am new to AWS environment and trying to solve how the data flow works. After successfully uploading CSV files from S3 to SageMaker notebook instance, I am stuck on doing the reverse.

I have a dataframe and want to upload that to S3 Bucket as CSV or JSON. The code that I have is below:

```
bucket='bucketname'
data_key = 'test.csv'
data_location = 's3://{}/{}'.format(bucket, data_key)
df.to_csv(data_location)
```

I assumed since I successfully used `pd.read_csv()` while loading, using `df.to_csv()` would also work but it didn't. Probably it is generating error because this way I cannot pick the privacy options while uploading a file manually to S3. Is there a way to upload the data to S3 from SageMaker?

Comment: I don't think you can just put a web URL in as the path for `to_csv`. Maybe you could try saving it as a local file, then uploading that with `requests`? Or converting it to a string somehow?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use a local file because one objective of the project is to try keeping everything on the cloud. Thanks for your comment @101arrowz

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One way to solve this would be to save the CSV to the local storage on the SageMaker notebook instance, and then use the S3 API's via `boto3` to upload the file as an s3 object. 
[S3 docs for `upload_file()` available here.](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_file)

Note, you'll need to ensure that your SageMaker hosted notebook instance has proper `ReadWrite` permissions in its IAM role, otherwise you'll receive a permissions error.

```
# code you already have, saving the file locally to whatever directory you wish
file_name = "mydata.csv" 
df.to_csv(file_name)
```

```
# instantiate S3 client and upload to s3
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.meta.client.upload_file(file_name, 'YOUR_S3_BUCKET_NAME', 'DESIRED_S3_OBJECT_NAME')
```

Alternatively, `upload_fileobj()` may help for parallelizing as a multi-part upload.

Comment: I am currently using this method, but I am trying to avoid saving a copy in Sagemaker since I am uploading thousands of csvs. Is there a way to upload to S3 without saving the csv files in Sagemaker as well?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `boto3` to upload a file but, given that you're working with dataframe and `pandas` you should consider `dask`. You can install it via `conda install dask s3fs`

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
```

## Read from S3

```py
df = dd.read_csv('s3://{}/{}'.format(bucket, data2read),
                 storage_options={'key': AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                                   'secret': AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY})
```

### Update

Now if you want to use this file as a `pandas` dataframe you should compute it as

```py
df = df.compute()
```

## Write to S3

To write back to S3 you should first load your `df` to dask with the number of partition (must be specified) you need

```py
df = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=N)
```

And then you can upload to S3

```py
df.to_csv('s3://{}/{}'.format(bucket, data2write),
          storage_options={'key': AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                           'secret': AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY})
```

### Update

Despite the `API` is similar the `to_csv` in `pandas` is not the same as the one in `dask` in particular the latter has the `storage_options` parameter.
Furthermore `dask` doesn't save to a unique file. Let me explain: if you decide that to write to `s3://my_bucket/test.csv` with `dask` then instead of have a file called `test.csv` you are going to have a folder with that name that contain `N` files where `N` is the number of partitions we decided before.

## Final Note

I understand that it could feel strange to save to multiple files but given that `dask` read all files on a folder, once you get used to, it could be very convenient.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @rpanai. When I run your code, I get the following error message: `TypeError: to_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'storage_options`

Comment: Is df a pandas or a dask dataframe?